# How to combine two sets of nginx rules?

Tags: linux, nginx

I need to use two sets of nginx rules on my server inside the server block of nginx.conf . Can you please help me with the syntax to combine these two set of rules ?

valid_referers none blocked server_names *.site.site site.site ;

if ($invalid_referer) {
  return   444;
}

and also this rule :

if ($http_referer = "") {  return 444; }

First one is to limit my files to only my website and the second one is to close connection for those who don't have any referrer .

Comment: https://nginx.org/r/valid_referers

Comment: not what I asked for .

Comment: Actually it is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Both rules terminate with a `return`, so you can just write one after the other.